# Passing table name and where condition dynamically into stored procedure and also taking all data into #table for future massaging

Tags: sql-server

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myreport]
    @lob_name VARCHAR(255), 
    @lob_id VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @Sql ='SELECT  TOP 100 l.id as lid,l.last_name as customer_name, l.phone_mobile into #maintable
               FROM customer l with (nolock) 
               LEFT JOIN customer_cstm as c ON l.id = c.id_c 
               LEFT JOIN' + @lob_name +' AS m ON m.id=l.motor_id
               LEFT JOIN report_retention p ON p.policy_no = m.policy_no
               WHERE l.deleted = 0  AND (l.set_lob_type ='+ @lob_id+') 
                 AND p.lob ='+ @lob_name+'
               ORDER BY l.id ASC'
    /*
    Some massaging will here then will select #table
    */

    SELECT * #maintable
```

I am passing these things bus can't copy in #table for massaging

1. I need to pass table dynamically
2. In where condition also pass dynamically parameters

Comment: You can't create a temp table in dynamic SQL and access it outside the dynamic section. And you haven't yet executed your SQL anyway. You need to create a temp table before you call your dynamic SQL.

Comment: if i create before dynamic query ,can I transfer all data into #table

Comment: Yes if it already exists then its available to the dynamic SQL as well.

Comment: Thank You @DaleBurrell It working.I have created hashtable in starting ans also I have added this code to pass data into #table    `SET @Sql ='Insert into #Cd_Report_table  SELECT `